# Serve react without a need of index.html

Tags: reactjs, express

Let's imagine i have a express server from where i can send react app file on browser request - app.js

```
fastify.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/index.html',
  handler: (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(app.js)
  }
})
```

On client side i want browser to accept it as index.html with react inside.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './src/App'

// Where to place all html?
render(<App />, document.getElementById('someid'))
```

To put it simple, i want to get rid of index.html and generate it dynamically.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your react app is just a JavaScript bundle where as browser can only understand Html and execute js.

Browser parses HTML and creates DOM tree, during this process it fetches all the JavaScript in script tags. And React is not HTML.

So you have to send index.html for that matter any html file is must be sent to the browser first.